# Lapack undefined reference

Tags: g++, lapack

I am new to g++ and lapack, and attempting to use them. I encountered a problem when I tried to compile the following naive code

```
#include <lapackpp.h>
int main()
{
    LaGenMatDouble A;
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the command

```
$g++ -L/usr/local/lib -llapackpp test2.cpp
```

where test2.cpp is the name of the cpp file, the terminal would give an error:

```
test2.cpp:1:22: fatal error: lapackpp.h: No such file or directory
```

But if I run the command:

```
$g++ -I/usr/local/include/lapackpp -L/usr/local/lib -llapackpp test2.cpp
```

the terminal would give an error:

```
/tmp/ccUi11DG.o: In function `main':  
test2.cpp:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `LaGenMatDouble::LaGenMatDouble()'  
test2.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `LaGenMatDouble::~LaGenMatDouble()'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

BTW, if I run the command

```
$pkg-config lapackpp --libs
```

the result is

```
-L/usr/local/lib -llapackpp
```

Could you please help me solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lapack requires fortran libraries, so that's where the `-lgfortran` comes from.  Moreover, it appears the exact way to provide that library for the compiler depends on the Linux distriburion.  From the [documentation](http://lapackpp.sourceforge.net/):

> *Requirements*
>
> This package requires the packages "blas", "lapack" (without the "++"), and a Fortran compiler. On most Linuxes these are available as pre-compiled binaries under the name "blas" and "lapack". For SuSE 10.x, the Fortran compiler is available as package "gfortran". For SuSE 9.x, the Fortran compiler is available as package "gcc-g77".

Not sure why `pkg-config lapackpp --libs` does not list `-lgfortran`

The `-I/usr/local/include/lapackpp` specifes the lapackpp-related header files.  Without it the compiler cannot find lapackpp.h when you try to include it (`#include <lapackpp.h>`)  -- see the compiler error in your question

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, Attila. I did a lot of google search when I tried to solve the problem. Everybody seems to use "-L/usr/local/lib" instead of "-I/usr/local/include/lapackpp", but this way seems not work on my computer. I am very curious about why. And I did not see many of them include explicitly "-lg2c" or "-lgfortran" in their linking command, but it seems it works fine on their computers. I am wondering why.

Comment: They might have their `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable set to include some common libs for convenience.  Note that `-L` (also, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, see above) specifes where the _linker_ should look for the libs specified with the `-l` (small L) options, whereas `-I` (capital i) specifies where the _compiler_ should look for the headers mentioned in `#include` directives

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem but would still wonder why it has to be so.
The only command that can link cpp file to lapackpp library is:

```
g++ foo.cpp -o foo -lgfortran -llapackpp -I/usr/local/include/lapackpp
```

It would not work without `-lgfortran`, or with `-I/usr/local/include/lapackpp` replaced by `-L/usr/local/lib`.

Does anyone have an answer?